# python: can't open file 'myexample.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, anaconda, sublimetext3

I installed Sublime Text 3 notepad to write Python3 and to see the .py files on true location i runned myexample.py (which is on desktop and just printed hello world) on CMD

```
cd Desktop 
python myexample.py
```

then I got an error message like

> python: can't open file 'myexample.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

it has to show me only

```
hello world
```

on cmd screen instead of that error. What might be wrong here?

I tried to write python3 on cmd, I checked the locations and the `myexample.py` is on desktop, i even tried to write anaconda to the cmd but couldn't solve it.

> python: can't open file 'myexample.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: do `ls` or 'dir' and show what are the contents. also `pwd` or 'cwd'.

Comment: As the error message says, `Python` doesn't find the `myexample.py` file. From the command shell, move to the folder where is `myexample.py` and try again.

Comment: @Vishal hello thanks for comment. I used 'dir' to see where is my file and realized its not on Desktop. Eventhough I physically saved the file on desktop. How can i move it to the Desktop on cmd or do you have any reccomendation to do it or not? thank you so much

Comment: you can use `move source <desktop_path>` on cmd